How to give an angular material checkbox a custom color
I'm in a situation where I want to give a checkbox a different color, maybe just th background color, but if possible the border and/or text color as well
<mat-checkbox [color]="color()"></mat-checkbox>

With the color attribute I'm only able set 'primary', 'accent' and 'warn'.
Right now I've only changed the border as follows
::ng-deep .mat-mdc-checkbox-checked .mdc-checkbox__background {
    border-color: #fff!important;
}

But this is not an ideal solution and feels a bit hacky, so I was wondering if Angular Material has a built-in way of doing this, perhaps through a CSS variable?

Check the docs, they have an example for a very similar case:
.some-container {
  --mdc-checkbox-unselected-hover-state-layer-color: #fff;
  --mdc-checkbox-unselected-hover-icon-color: #fff;
}

Providing new values for their CSS variables is the preferred solution, because the internally used DOM elements and classes may change at any time.
v19 update
With Angular Material v19 or later, the new recommendation is to use the new overrides SCSS mixins. Also starting from v19, the docs contain a new "Styling" tab where you can see which tokens you can override. For example, for the checkbox, you can now override the styles like the following:
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

.some-container {
  @include mat.checkbox-overrides((
    unselected-hover-state-layer-color: #fff,
    unselected-hover-icon-color: #fff,
  ));
}


The weird thing is that they don't mention (except for the 2 you mention) any css variables. After some searching and trail and error I found the one I'm interested in, which is the background color of the selected state: --mdc-checkbox-selected-icon-color

@JeanlucaScaljeri yes it would be great to have a list of all available CSS variables in the docs. Right now the easiest way is to inspect the element in the DevTools and find out by yourself. I found an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/28933

@JeanlucaScaljeri with v19 there will be a new recommended approach, updated my answer.
